# Constructing a metric on a Lie Group

Tags: metric-spaces, lie-groups, riemannian-geometry

Given a connected Lie Group $G$ is there a standard method for constructing the metric tensor?

One can of course expand a group element $g=e^{x^ie_i}$ where $e_i$ are basis vectors of the Lie algebra about the identity up to linear order and compute the metric in this manner, but is there a more direct way?

An example would also be appreciated.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

There is such a (bi-invariant) metric on a Lie group (isomorphic to a compact Lie group times $\mathbb{R}^{n}$). It is the one induced by [the Killing form](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Killing_form). For more input on this, see the mathoverflow discussion on the topic:

https://mathoverflow.net/questions/32554/why-the-killing-form

It should be pointed out that you *do not* need the exponential map to construct the metric, which is defined on the tangent space $T_{p}g, g\in G$, not on the group itself. All you need is a nicely behaved symmetric bilinear form under the group action. The explicit construction can be found at [here](http://isites.harvard.edu/fs/docs/icb.topic1301985.files/2301320.pdf).

---

Update:  Yor pointed out in the comments that for a non-semisimple compact Lie group there is a bi-invariant metric, but it is not induced by the Killing form, as the Killing form degenerates on the center. To solve this, write $\mathfrak{g}=\mathfrak{a}\times \mathfrak{s}$. The Killing form induces a metric on $\mathfrak{s}$ and we put an arbitrary metric on $\mathfrak{a}$.

Comment: I don't think Lie groups in general admits a bi-invariant metric though.

Comment: @Qidi: Yes, compactness is needed.

Comment: @Bombyxmori: Compactness is useful, but not required: all abelian groups admit bi-invariant metrics! [A Lie group that admits a bi-invariant metric is the product of a compact group and a copy of some $\mathbb{R}^m$ (Milnor, 1976).]

Comment: @CatalinZara: I only know the proof in the compact case. If I am not confused, Milnor's claim is that a lie group admits a bi-invariant metric can be decomposed as a product group, not every (connected) Lie group admits a bi-invariant metric. I have yet to read the paper itself, so thanks for the pointer.

Comment: @Bombyxmori: What I'm saying is that there are groups that admit bi-invariant metrics and are not compact.

Comment: @Bombyxmori for a non-semisimple compact Lie group there is a bi-invariant metric, but it is *not* induced by the Killing form, as the Killing form degenerates on the center.

Comment: @YCor: Thanks! Do you mind give an answer to the topic to clarify? My Lie theory knowledge is getting rusty.

Comment: Write $\mathfrak{g}=\mathfrak{s}\times\mathfrak{a}$ with $\mathfrak{s}$ semisimple and $\mathfrak{a}$ abelian, and take the Killing form on $\mathfrak{s}$, and an arbitrary scalar product on $\mathfrak{a}$.

Comment: @YCor: I see - I will try to update the answer tonight.

Comment: The link to `isites.harvard.edu` is broken. I'm also unable to find any copy saved on the Wayback Machine.

Answer (score 8):

You ask about *the* metric tensor of a Lie group, but such a thing does not exist. What you can do, though, is to (arbitrarily) choose a scalar product $\langle, \rangle _e$ in $T_e G$ and then by (left) translations define $\langle, \rangle _g = (L_g) _* \langle, \rangle _e$, that is for $u,v \in T_g G$ define $\langle u, v \rangle _g = \langle \mathrm d L_g ^{-1} (u), \mathrm d L_g ^{-1} (v) \rangle _e$, where $L_g (x) = gx$. This is a left-invariant Riemann tensor, which in turn gives rise to a left-invariant distance $d$, i.e. $d(gx, gy) = d(g,h)$ for all $g,x,y \in G$. Neither the metric tensor, nor the associated distance need be right-invariant (and, symetrically, if you construct them to be right-invariant, they need not be left-invariant).

The following result is taken from [Chapter 17](http://web.archive.org/web/20210506232817/https://www.cis.upenn.edu/%7Ecis610/cis610-15-sl17.pdf) of "Linear Algebra, Manifolds, Riemannian Metrics, Lie Groups and Lie algebra, with Applications to Robotics, Vision and Machine Learning" by Jean Gallier:

> If $G$ is connected, $\langle, \rangle$ defined above is bi-invariant (meaning left- and right-invariant) if and only if $\langle [u,v], w \rangle = - \langle v, [u,w] \rangle$ for all $u,v,w \in T_e G$.

If $G$ is compact, then one may define a bi-invariant Riemann tensor $\langle, \rangle '$ from a left- (or right-) invariant one $\langle, \rangle$ by Haar-integrating the latter: $\langle u, v \rangle ' = \int _G \langle \mathrm d L_g u, \mathrm d L_g v \rangle_{gx} \ \mathrm d g$ for all $u,v \in T_x G$ and $x \in G$.

If $G$ is semisimple, then its Lie algebra $\mathfrak g \simeq T_e G$ possesses a preferred scalar product - the Kiling form (or its opposite, depending on the sign convention used), and this in turn gives rise to a preferred metric tensor on $G$.

Comment: Excuse me... would you please give me a help? So... it seems like you constructed a metric by choosing an inner product on $T_e G$, then passing out to other points $g\in G$ via left translation $L_g$, right? Note that a metric is a smooth positive covariant 2-tensor. So... my question is why the metric $g\to L_g$ is smooth?