# Is there a canonical metric for a Lie group manifold?

Tags: group-theory, differential-geometry, metric-spaces, manifolds, lie-groups

A Lie group can be defined as a *differentiable manifold*. Is it possible to import the notion of *Riemannian metric on differentiable manifolds* to define a canonical metric on a Lie group?

Comment: Not in general. Compact connected simple Lie groups such as $SU(n)$ have bi-invariant metrics that are unique up to scale or something like that.

Comment: See also [this question](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/2062811/constructing-a-metric-on-a-lie-group).

Answer (score 4):

1. Each compact connected simple Lie group has a unique (up to scalar) biinvariant Riemannian metric.
2. Every Lie group $G$ admits a (canonical) finite-dimensional family of left-invariant Riemannian metrics. The space of this metrics is parameterized by the space of congruence classes of positive-definite quadratic forms on $R^n$ ($n=dim(G)$).
3. If $G$ is a simple Lie group with a maximal compact subgroup $K$ then $G$ admits a unique (up to scalar) left-invariant Riemannian metric which is right-invariant under $K$. This includes (1) as a special case.